# disable Ionic 2 touch events system for leaflet map (draw controller)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic2, leaflet, leaflet.draw

Can anyone please show me how to disable data-tap on ionic 2, in leaflet map div?

On Ionic-v1, the trick was to input `data-tap-disabled="true"` in the div map container (ion-content).

I installed this leaflet draw plugin [leaflet-draw-with-touch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-draw-with-touch) with touch support for mobile, and unfortunately, I still can't draw on the map with the tablet pen...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?  I can use leaflet but only after clicking on another element of the application.  Without clicking on something else, I can't use the leaflet buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Click events are handled by node_modules/ionic-angular/tap-click/tap-click.js

The method `shouldCancelClick()` returns true when `this.dispatchClick` is undefined or false, which is set by `pointerStart()` bound to the mousedown event.

As a workaround I trigger a mousedown + mouseup event once the map was loaded:

```
@ViewChild('map') mapNode: ElementRef;

ionViewDidEnter() {

    // init map here
    ....

    var e1 = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    e1.initEvent('mousedown', true, true);
    this.mapNode.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(e1);

    var e2 = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    e2.initEvent('click', true, true);
    this.mapNode.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(e2);
 }
```